# Authenticate multiple web applications with same Azure AD App

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

We have multiple slots for each web application which are authenticating users via Azure AD. Currently we are creating one Azure AD app for each slot and so if there are 4 web applications with 3 slots each, we are creating 12 Azure AD app with just change in reply url's. Is there a way we can use the same app to authenticate all web applications & slots? Either via config or code.

Comment: Have you looked into making a multi-tenant app in Azure AD?  With that in place you can deploy a single copy of the app and authorize users against the "common" endpoint in Azure AD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can create a single Azure AD App and add a reply URL for each of your 12 slots. No other changes would be needed except to ensure each of your web app slots are configured to point to the single Azure AD app.

It's theoretically more secure to use separate Azure AD apps for each web app since there is greater isolation, but what you ask is technically possible.

Comment: Got it. Somehow I was not able to get this working before. Seems to work fine now. Thanks